# Read html where required table needs user's input

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I want to read the table from 'https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/bitfinex/', however I need  'pair' to be set to 'USD'. By default it is set to 'All'. Changing 'USD' to 'All' doesnt change the url or anything so when I give the link to pandas_datareader it finds only default table.

Is there any way I can read the needed table?

Comment: page uses `JavaScript` to filter table when you select `USD` - so you can't get this by changing URL.  It seems it already has all data in memory and maybe you can find this in HTML in some place - but it may need something more then `pandas_datareader` but `requests`+`beautifulsoup` (or `lxml`)

Comment: it seems you can only get all data from page and later filter them in Python to get only needed pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this page has all data in HTML and it uses JavaScript to filter data in table when you select `USD`. So it doesn't use other `URL` to get data and it doesn't use `AJAX` to load them from other `URL` - so you can't get it by changing `URL`

You can only get all data and later filter rows

```
import pandas as pd

all_dfs = pd.read_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/bitfinex/')

df = all_dfs[2]

df[ df['Pair'].str.endswith('USD') ]
```